# How to get column comment from hibernate metadata in oracle?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I have the following property from *.hbm.xml file for hibernate mapping:

```
.
.
.
<property name="personGroup">
    <column name="TST_KLPD_PERSONGROUP" not-null="true" sql-type="NUMBER(10)">
        <comment>MY COMMENT</comment>
    </column>
</property>
.
.
.
```

In run time I get all column metadata with the following code:

```
ClassMetadata hibernateMetadata = map.get(key);
if (hibernateMetadata instanceof AbstractEntityPersister) {
    AbstractEntityPersister persister = (AbstractEntityPersister) hibernateMetadata;
    List<String> columnNames = getColumnNames(persister);
    for (String prob : columnNames) {
        String columnName = persister.getPropertyColumnNames(prob)[0];
    }
}
```

Now, how can I get the column comment of the property prob?

Answer (score 0):

I hop it will help you:

```
configuration.getClassMapping([entity class name]).getTable().getColumn([column number]).getComment()
```

please replace the [entity class name] and [column number].